# How do I take a screenshot with DX11?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm writing a plugin for a DX11 game and I need to take a screenshot and save it to a file. I found some code snippets that use the function `D3DX11SaveTextureToFile` but I just couldn't get it to work. Here's what I have so far: (error checking and unrelated code removed for simplicity)

```
void screenshot(IDXGISwapChain *pSwapChain)
{
    ID3D11Device *pDevice;
    pSwapChain->GetDevice(__uuidof(ID3D11Device), reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pDevice));

    ID3D11DeviceContext *pContext;
    pDevice->GetImmediateContext(&pContext);

    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
    pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pBackBuffer));

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC txtDesc;
    pBackBuffer->GetDesc(&txtDesc);
    txtDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    txtDesc.BindFlags = 0;
    txtDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    // txtDesc.Format == DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM

    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBufferStaging;
    pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&txtDesc, nullptr, &pBackBufferStaging);
    pContext->CopyResource(pBackBufferStaging, pBackBuffer);

    HRESULT hr = D3DX11SaveTextureToFileA(pContext, pBackBufferStaging, D3DX11_IFF_PNG, "E:\\screenshot.png");
    // hr == E_FAIL

    pBackBufferStaging->Release();
    pBackBuffer->Release();
}
```

I got a `E_FAIL` error and after some research it seems that `D3DX11SaveTextureToFile` doesn't support the texture format `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM`, which is used by the game I assume. If I manually set the format to something like `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` the function will succeed but I will just get a black image. I think `CopyResource` requires that the source and destination have the same format.

I'm aware that there's the DirectXTK library but I'm stuck with VS2013 and DirectXTK doesn't seem to support it if I read its readme correctly.

**EDIT**
DirectXTK/DirectXTex worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ScreenGrab) module from the *DirectX Tool Kit* is your best bet. It can write either `DDS` files or various formats supported by WIC, `JPG` included:

```
using namespace DirectX;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBuffer;
HRESULT hr = swapChain->GetBuffer( 0,
    __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ),
   reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>( backBuffer.GetAddressOf() ) );
if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    hr = SaveWICTextureToFile( immContext.Get(), backBuffer.Get(),
                GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, L"SCREENSHOT.JPG" );
}
DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);
```

I recently dropped support for Visual Studio 2013 from my GitHub projects--see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2018/04/30/github-nuget-and-vso/) for some details. If you can't upgrade, you can use a slightly older April 2018 [release](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/releases/tag/apr2018) which does support VS 2013.

> D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 are all deprecated along with the DirectX SDK generally per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx).